# How to check HVAC efficiency?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I recently installed a Goodman 16 seer condensers with Goodman 96% efficiency furnace.
The condensers when received mentioned 14 seer on yellow label. When I called, the Goodman tech said, the min it will operate is at 14 seer, however if right components parts are used while setting up, I will get a 16 seer from the condensers.

I am confused by the reply, does anyone know how to test the HVAC system to confirm the entire system is operating at 16 seers? My installer said he used reasonable parts and he cannot guarantee anything. I am left with an expensive system, but don't know whether I am getting 16 seer output

Thanks for helping.
Marc

Comment: If they where offered and sold as 16 seer and you got 14 seer, would say some funny business is going on.  Would check the wording quite carefully of the description of the condensers.  Testing of a system probably would need professionals and equipment, not a DIY job.

Comment: Using a 14 seer coil if sold as a 16 seer unit it would need to be upgraded from an orifice to a TXV (thermally controlled throttle valve). Other than this there is not much you can do, as far as reasonable parts ??? What does this mean they used the right sized coil the efficiency of the coil is based on the design. Without additional information it sounds like you were taken advantage of.